# Statistics for and Details About Open Source Swing Projects

Tags: open-source, swing

I'm looking for process-relative information on open-source Swing projects:

- how the task was described
- how many developers were involved
- how much time the solution was taken
- etc.

Are there any open source (online) chronicles in that direction?  I strongly prefer projects that include the authors' names.

I watched [this project](http://www.japura.org/) and it seems fine but still I couldn't find any information concerning some current project task(s), its developers group, some chronicles (tips, milestones, feedbacks etc)

For example if I see [this swing component](http://www.japura.org/arrowbutton) I'd like to know the above information.

Comment: Suggesting projects to work on or join is explicitly mentioned in our [FAQ] as being off-topic.

Comment: No I mean why they hide projects authors' names? That is the question

Comment: You might want to edit your post to be more clear about what you're looking for. Your title, 1st, and 5th paragraph (which is the only one that contains an actual question) seem to indicate that you're looking for projects to work on.

Comment: No, I am looking for projects developing process information (chronicles) and want people to share some links or tips is they know some unique ones.

Comment: You need to edit your post to include this information if you want it reopened, however that still sounds like it is not constructive. We expect questions to be about finding a solution to a problem, not to turn into a list of projects, links, or tips. Since you're looking for projects of a particular type, what are you trying to learn from them? Asking that might be better suited to this format. If you need more help, feel free to ask [on Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).

Comment: "what are you trying to learn from them?" I want to see how do they organize developing process; For example if I see http://www.japura.org/arrowbutton I'd like to know how the task was described, how many developers were involved (or how many should be involved), how much time the solution was taken etc? Can someone answer is there any open source (online) chronicles in that direction? Maybe someone can share some examples ... Oh my... is it so hard question or something? :(

Comment: You need to edit your post to clearly state what you want to learn, not post it as comments. Make your title and body extremely clear and specific, and then flag this post for review. Leaving comments is insufficient to have a question reopened.

Comment: OK, I'll try to be more specific

Comment: I completely rewrote your post to make it conform more closely to the rules of this site and voted for your question and voted to reopen it.  You are welcome to undo my edits if you don't like them.

Comment: Oh, thank you, Glen :) The edit seems fine. Anyway, for some reason it is still closed :(

Comment: @user592704 - reopening takes 5 community votes. It will take time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You probably want to look at [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/)**

Ohloh provides statistics on a vast array of open source projects, many of which are categorized in terms of the technology that they use. For example, a [simple search on Swing](http://www.ohloh.net/p?ref=homepage&q=swing) yields 241 pages of projects for you to data mine.

Comment: It is a quite interesting resource. Thank you. But you mean is it open source platform where developers can create open source projects online as a team?

Comment: Generally developers of open source projects will register with ohloh to get more exposure. Ohloh then provides statistics. It is not like Github where collaboration is more integrated.